# If there exists $m,n\geq2$ such that $x^{m}y^{n}=yx$, for any $x,y\in M$, then prove that the operation is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

> Let $M$ be a set, not null, and $*$ an operation that is associative. If there exist $m,n\geq2$ such that $x^{m}y^{n}=yx$, for any $x,y\in M$, then prove that the operation is commutative.

Now, I obtained a result by $x{\rightarrow}yxy^{-1}$ such that $yx=(yxy^{-1})^my^n=yx^my^{n-1}=yx^my^ny^{-1}=yyxy^{-1}$ and from here $yx=yyxy^{-1}{\Rightarrow}xy=yx$.

> However, this works only if my set is a group. How can I adapt this to the form of the set?

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent. You say you're using an operation $\ast$, yet you compute using concatenation; this is fine, I suppose, but it is a bit sloppy.

Comment: Just a bit, not a lot. But fair point, @MikeEarnest.

Comment: Even assuming there were inverses for $y$, from $(yxy^{-1})^my^n$ you get $y(yxy^{-1})=y^2xy^{-1}$, not $yx$.

Comment: That's consistent with the exercise, @ArturoMagidin. (EDIT: I think I see what you mean now though . . . )

Comment: @Shaun: Sorry, I'm confused. What is "consistent with the exercise"? The OP starts with $yx$, and claims this is equal to $(yxy^{-1})^my^n$, and I don't see how this is justified.

Comment: No, I'm the one that's confused, @ArturoMagidin. Sorry. You're quite right. What I thought you meant was that $(\color{red}{yxy^{-1}})^m\color{blue}{y}^n \neq \color{blue}{y}\color{red}{x}$ was the issue (*without the OP's reasoning, just yours* if you see what I mean . . . ). (Please excuse the handwaving colours.)

Answer (score 4):

In the four Lemmas that follow, $z$ is an arbitrary element of $M$.

> **Lemma $1$**: $z^2=z^{m+n}$.

*Proof:* $z^2=zz=z^{m}z^{n}=z^{m+n}.$

> **Lemma $2$**: $z^3=z^{2m+n}.$

*Proof:* $z^3=zz^2=z^{2m}z^{n}=z^{2m+n}.$

> **Lemma $3$**: $z^2=z^2\cdot z^{m-1}$.

*Proof:*
\begin{align}
z^2
  &\stackrel1=z^{m+n}
\\&=z^3z^{m+n-3}
\\&\stackrel2=z^{2m+n}z^{m+n-3}
\\&=z^{m+n}z^{2m+n-3}
\\&\stackrel1=z^{2}z^{2m+n-3}
\\&=z^{m+n}z^{m-1}
\\&\stackrel1=z^{2}z^{m-1}.
\end{align}

> **Lemma** $4$: $
> z^2=z^2\cdot z^{n-1}.
> $

*Proof:* Should be obvious by the symmetry of the assumptions in $m,n$.

---

With these Lemmas under our belt, we can solve the problem at hand.

\begin{align}
xy
  &=y^mx^n
\\&=x^{mn}y^{mn}
\\&=x^{m-2}x^{2}(x^{n-1})^my^{n-2}y^2(y^{m-1})^n
\\&\stackrel{3}=x^{m-2}x^{2}(x^{n-1})^my^{n-2}y^2
\\&\stackrel{4}=x^{m-2}x^{2}y^{n-2}y^2
\\&=x^my^n
\\&=yx
\end{align}
In step $\stackrel{3}=$, we apply Lemma $3$ a total of $n$ times with $z=y$, each time eliminating one copy of $y^{m-1}$ next to the $y^2$. In $\stackrel{4}=$, we apply Lemma $4$ $m$ times with $z=x$.

Note $x^0$ refers to the empty product, so $x^{m-2}$ is valid (here is where we need $m,n\ge 2$). This is not an element of $M$, but the absence of a product.